# What are good ways to architect a custom "ClaimsAuthorizationManager" Windows Identity Foundation class?

Tags: .net, asp.net, wif, windows-identity, claims-based-identity

I am working on the very first project at my office where we will be using "Windows Identity Foundation" with Claims-Based-Authorization.  To this end, Microsoft .net provides the ClaimsAuthorizationManager abstract class.  In order to use this class, you override two methods: the constructor and `CheckAccess(context as ClaimsAuthorizationContext)`.

The constructor sets everything up; then when the user accesses something, such as a web page, `CheckAccess` gets called with a parameter which indicates the user, the resource to be accessed, and the action to be taken on the resource.  For example, `CheckAccess` could be called to see if the user `Bob` should be given access to the resource `http://www.mysite.com/SecretPage.aspx` to perform action `GET`.  `CheckAccess` simply returns `true` or `false`.  Windows Identity Foundation gives us the flexibility to implement `CheckAccess` almost any way imaginable!

In the code samples that Microsoft provides, `CheckAccess` is configured to allow access to a user only if he has a birthday claim that indicates age 21 or older.  This policy is given in plain-text in the web.config and read in the `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` constructor.

In my office, we use SQL to keep track of almost all of our data, so in my case. I believe that it makes sense to program the `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` to read data from SQL to determine if a user may or may not access a resource.  However, there is a myriad of different possible policies.  I want to create a `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` that will be useful in the current project and that I can build upon and improve in the future without having to rip and replace the project I create today.

What are the most important things to bear in mind as I proceed with this project?

UPDATE: I have been working on a system of representing required-claim policies as strings.  I use binary-tree logic to group together policies.  I maintain a database of claims associated with "resources" and "actions".

Has anyone else here built a ClaimsAuthorizationManager class?

Comment: I see I finally have received a suggestion.

On my own, I have come up with a way of representing policies for access to a page or resource as strings, such as minAge(30)+roleRequired("Supervisor") meaning the user must be at least 30 years old or be in the "Supervisor" role.  I wrote some binary tree logic to group policies together.

What I find more difficult is coming up with a way of saying, if the user wants to perform action A or resource R, then how do we determine which policy the user must have the claims for?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is encouraging that you are looking forward trying not to write dead code BUT I think you are getting ahead of yourself.

You need to produce one or more spikes that ARE treated as throw-away to determine for yourself what makes sense for your particular scenario.

That said, if all of your rules are in the db, create a sproc base CAM that reads the sproc name from the config file. The CheckAccess args are not going to change so the sproc signature can be immutable allowing you to switch them out as needed.

Comment: I have written some code.  I can write and parse a string representing what criteria the user's claims must satisfy, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to associate a policy with resources and actions...

I think that in my DB, it will require multiple tables to indicate  mappings of "resources" and "actions" to "policies"

Comment: I do have a working prototype of a ClaimsAuthorizationManager that requires that the user be in a role to access designated web pages.